# How to remove and write new line while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made small python scraper which should find emails from loaded `.txt` file,in where are line by line url links to scrape.

Iam trying to write them to the another `.text` file but somehow I'm not able to write **new line** `for each` new scraped link loaded from `.txt file` and also there are some disturbing `[' n\` this kind of characters which keep writting to the text file even they are not presented in url I scraping.

My scraper:

```
def scrapeEmails():
    global reqs, _lock, success, fails, rps, rpm

    with open(os.path.join("proxies.txt"), "r") as f:
        proxies = f.read().splitlines()
    with open(os.path.join("links_toscrape.txt"), "r") as f:
        channelLinks = f.read().splitlines()
    rndChannelLinks = random.choice(channelLinks)

    URL = rndChannelLinks + "/about"
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    proxies = {"https": "http://"+proxy}

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies).text, "html.parser") 
    _description = soup.find("meta", property="og:description")
    _content = _description["content"] if _description else "No meta title given"

    #for s in _content:
    if "@" in _content.lower():
        __email = re.findall("([\s]{0,10}[\w.]{1,63}@[\w.]{1,63}[\s]{0,10})", _content)
        cleanEmail = [x.replace("\n", "") for x in __email]
        print("Email: ",  cleanEmail)

        with open("scraped_emails.txt") as f:
            f.write(str(cleanEmail))
            f.close()
    else:
        print("Email of YouTube channel " + URL + " not found.")
```

Comment: Could you please specify resultant txt file, in which you are writing?

Comment: @AdityaSoni what you mean? you mean what it scrape ? the output of email? if yes it is like this something [][' email232@gmail.com ', ' email123@gmail.com']

Comment: @AdityaSoni actually the code should find using regex email and write it line by line in output txt thats all i try to do

Comment: Could you please specify the output of above code, like what does `cleanEmail` contains?

Comment: @AdityaSoni cleanemail output shows this: Email:  [' email123@hotmail.com']